# Which Open Source Crawler is best?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am comparing these four Nutch / Heritrix / OpenPipeLine / Apache Tika
Which one is best? What are merits and demerits of each?
I would like to have some extendible crawler that can crawl a list of websites and can be modified if needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Nutch** is the most all around of them, extremely configurable. Tried with 100m documents. Trustworthy.

**Heritrix** works fine too, but not better than **Nutch**.

You can give **Crawler4j** a try if you need to crawl fast.

To do an introductory crawl and use and configure the crawler easily with a simple user interface, you can try **websphinx**.

**Tika** isn't a crawler : [it's a toolkit detects and extracts metadata and structured text content](http://tika.apache.org/)

I had a job that required crawling, but **OpenPipeLine** wasn't in the list of favourite crawlers. It has an UI, job scheduler; it's used for enterprise solutions. As you just want to crawl some websites, you won't need such things.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't researched the crawlers you mention but I know that the one I wrote is extensible and can be modified. It can also be used with AJAX and "javascript-only" websites (i.e. sites using the Google Web Toolkit).

The name is forklabs-javaxpcom and can be found at http://code.google.com/p/forklabs-javaxpcom/.